# Deobfuscate loadstring Lua

Tags: lua

I need help with my loadstring, i lost my source of script and my last rest of program is loadstring (i have obfuscated for other people, but i don't have backup).

for example help me with this loadstring:

```
\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\16\0\0\0\64\108\111\97\100\115\116\114\105\110\103\46\108\117\97\0\2\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\5\0\0\0\36\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\28\64\128\0\30\0\128\0\1\0\0\0\4\6\0\0\0\70\117\100\101\114\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\5\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\6\64\64\0\65\128\0\0\28\64\0\1\30\0\128\0\3\0\0\0\4\3\0\0\0\105\111\0\4\6\0\0\0\119\114\105\116\101\0\4\45\0\0\0\84\101\115\116\97\110\100\111\44\32\116\101\115\116\97\109\101\110\116\111\115\44\32\116\101\115\116\97\100\111\115\32\112\101\108\111\115\32\116\101\115\116\101\115\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
```

How to deobfuscate Loadstring? ( i am novice please help with details ).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lua code deobfuscation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961156/lua-code-deobfuscation)

Comment: This is not obfuscated code. It's Lua 5.1 bytecode.

Comment: If it were easy to de-obfuscate code, there'd be no point to obfuscating it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You may try LuaDec or some other decompiler (there is a section on [this Wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools)), but it may be a good exercise to rewrite it from scratch. The quality of the decompiled code also depends on whether you left any debug information in it or not.