# Lua desobfuscation

Tags: lua, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I was checking some Lua source, trying to get and learn from them, but it seems there are encoded & obsfuscated.

I decoded it using base64 decode, but still unreadable.

Is there any ways to desobfuscate it?

```
LuaR“


æÆì~>o¢by„A@€ÁÀAA†AÅÂAFB„K¥Jƒƒ„JÃB…¥CJƒ†¥ƒJƒƒ†ŒCÃ€C€‹ÀÝ€EÃ€ Ã€…ŠÃ
âƒcþåÃ%eD‹Á„…AÅEÁFA†ÆÁGA‡ŠÄÅ    Š„ÅŠF
ŠDÆ
Š„FŠÄÆŠGŠDÇŠ„G
ŠÄÇ
ŠH‹Á‡ˆAÈHÁIA‰ÉÁ JAŠ
ÁJ‹AËKÁ L   AŒ  Ì   Á
M
A
Í
Á
ÁJ‹AËKÁ L   AŒ  Ì   Á
M
A
Í
Á
```

Comment: Seems like compiled bytecode. Check the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961156/lua-code-deobfuscation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a precompiled Lua 5.2 script.

You can see its contents with `luac -l -p foo`.

Make sure you use `luac` from Lua 5.2. If in doubt, try `luac -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: [luadec](https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec)

Just curious, why did you tried base64? That chunk you provided is a simple lua code, translated to lua vm bytecodes. it is not even obfuscated.

Comment: Because what I got before the code was between base64decode().

Answer (score 0):

This is compiled lua source. You can use [this tool](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-04/msg00606.html) to decompile. It isn't actually obfuscated.